# Get Mail received date JavaMail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

How can I get the received date of the email through JavaMail? I would like to like to print the received date as output. Is there any method to call the received mail date and print it?

```
System.out.println(recievedDate);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this method

[getReceivedDate() in javax.mail.Message class](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/docs/api/jakarta/mail/Message.html#getReceivedDate--)